# Pass ResourceSet as parameter from .aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have a function, which has one parameter, a ResourceSet.

```
public DataTable getData(ResourceSet res)
{
    //do something    
}
```

When I call it from code behind like this, it's working fine, the ResourceSet is correct.

```
getData(Resources.res_Main.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, false));
```

I would like to use the getData function to bind the datasource to a DropDownList from the aspx file.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlist" runat="server" DataSource='<%# getData(Resources.res_Main.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, false)) %>' DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value" />
```

but in this case the res parameter will be null and it throws a NullReferenceException also.
How can I solve it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the datasource first, else it will load as an empty datasource. When you compile the page and it loads you get null as default, you need pass the datasource you want and bind it to load correctly